# [Solved]Catkin_make msg and srv error

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone.
I am following the tutorial here to set up msg and srv: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)

After I added all things to my tutorials file, I got this output

```
    CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:224 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on the catkin package 'message_runtime' which must
  therefore be listed as a run dependency in the package.xml
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:104 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:712: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

And I went to the CMakeLists.txt:104 to check what is wrong. Here's the code.

```
 catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES beginner_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy std_msgs
   DEPENDS system_lib
 )
```

There was a note for this code in the page of the tutorial, but I couldn't understand what I really should do for it.

In the tutorial, they said
"Also make sure you export the message runtime dependency. "

```
catkin_package(
  ...
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime ...
  ...)
```

It was commented lines, so I uncommented them and then I got the error.
So I also tried commenting out them, and I got an error too.

Thank you for any help!!

Here is the entire CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a exec_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 add_message_files(
   FILES
   Num.msg
 )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 add_service_files(
   FILES
   AddTwoInts.srv
 )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
 catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES beginner_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy std_msgs
   DEPENDS system_lib
 )

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/beginner_tutorials.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/beginner_tutorials_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables for installation
## See http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_executables.html
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark libraries for installation
## See http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_libraries.html
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_beginner_tutorials.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355463/%5Bsolved%5Dcatkin_make-msg-and-srv-error/) by [hiro1117](https://answers.ros.org/users/55764/hiro1117/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2020-06-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-06-21**:
Share the entire CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [hiro1117](https://answers.ros.org/users/55764/hiro1117/) on 2020-06-21**:
Thank you for your comment. I uploaded the entire txt.file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out that I haven't uncomment them in the package.xml:

```
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
```

---

Originally posted by [hiro1117](https://answers.ros.org/users/55764/hiro1117/) with karma: 28 on 2020-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-06-22**:
Can you mark the question as asnwered (if you feel is already answered)? just below the vote button in this response.

**Comment by [hiro1117](https://answers.ros.org/users/55764/hiro1117/) on 2020-06-22**:
Hello, Solrac3589.
Thank you for your comment.
I would love to, but I need 10 points to mark my answer and I do not have so far..
I'm sorry..